# Producing combinations of lambda functions compositions

Tags: python, design-patterns, lambda, functional-programming

I am facing a challenging issue in order to make my Python3 code more elegant.

Suppose I have a number function with variable number of different inputs, for example something like this:

```
def fun1(a,b):
    return a+b

def fun2(c,d,e):
    return c*d + e

def fun3(x):
    return x*x
```

These functions needs to be agglomerated in a single function that needs to be used as the optimization function of a numerical solver.

However I need to create different combinations of various operations with these functions, like for example multiplying the output of the first two functions and summing by the third.

The manual solution is to create a specific lambda function:

```
fun = lambda x : fun1(x[0],x[1])*fun2(x[2],x[3],x[4]) + fun3(x[4])
```

but the number of functions I have is large and I need to produce all the possibile combinations of them.
I would like to systematically be able to compose these functions and always knowing the mapping from the arguments of higher level function  `fun` to the lower level arguments of each single function.
In this case I manually specified that `x[0]` corresponds to the argument `a` of `fun1`, `x[1]` corresponds to argument `b` of `fun1` etcetera.

Any idea?

Comment: all different combination of what though? Will the pattern always be `f` * `g` + `h`? Or are we talking all different patterns as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to do what is known as [symbolic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_regression). This problem is often solved via some variation on genetic algorithms which encode the functional relationships in the genes and then optimise based on a fitness function which includes the prediction error as well as a term which penalises more complicated relationships.

Here are two libraries which solve this problem for you:

- [GPLearn](http://gplearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#intro)
- [dcgpy](http://darioizzo.github.io/d-CGP/)

The following classes provide a rudimentary way of composing functions and keeping track of the number of arguments each one requires, which appears to be the main problem you have:

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.n = f.__code__.co_argcount

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.f(*x)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Add(self, other)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Mul(self, other)

class Operator:
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.n = left.n + right.n

class Mul(Operator):
    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.left(x[:self.left.n]) * self.right(x[self.left.n:])

class Add(Operator):
    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.left(x[:self.left.n]) + self.right(x[self.left.n:])
```

To use them, you first create wrappers for each of your functions:

```
w1 = Wrapper(fun1)
w2 = Wrapper(fun2)
w3 = Wrapper(fun3)
```

Then you can add and multiply the wrappers to get a new function-like object:

```
(w1 + w2*w3)([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped me discovering a new thing. However I think I don't need that level of complexity, I've managed to find a first form of the solution, by using argument unpacking and finding the arguments of a function by accessing to the `__code__` field of it.

Comment: @linello I've added a concrete implementation of a way to compose functions

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution:

```
def fun1(a,b):
    return a+b

def fun2(c,d,e):
    return c+d+e


def compose(f1,f2):
    n1 = len(f1.__code__.co_varnames)
    n2 = len(f2.__code__.co_varnames)

    F1 = lambda x : f1(*[x[i] for i in range(0,n1)])*f2(*[x[i] for i in range(n1,n1+n2)])
    return F1

print(compose(fun1,fun2)([1,2,3,4,5]))
```